# How to get scaffolding to work in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, scaffolding

I can't seem to get the scaffolding grid to work for my Bootstrap code. The two different div classes are appearing on different lines and are both the full width of the screen. Any help would be much appreciated

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <p><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum!</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 offset2">
            <h4><a href="#">Same Line?</a></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using the bootstrap 3 stylesheet with version 2.3 html.

use this stylesheet: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css

vs

http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: Do you have a recommendation of which one to use? Is there more out there for Bootstrap 2.3 or 3?

Comment: I would definitely go with bootstrap 3 as the grid itself has a lot more options and multiple css break points. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That should be working correctly. Do you have any example online? (The only thing I can think of without more detail is that you do not have the correct bootstrap css file loading in the header)

Comment: (You didn't ask me but I figured I would chime in anyways) Bootstrap 2.3 currently has a lot more documentation out there since it has been around for longer, but if you want to use something more current and flexible but with potentially less of an established base of commonly answered questions, I'd go with 3.